# How to unload flash application

Tags: ajax, actionscript-3, flash

I load flash application through ajax and later I want to unload it completely. This operation could be repeated several times. How this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use swfobject, you can use removeSWF method in order to do that.
From SWFObject documentation:

> Removes a SWF from your web page. Is especially built to safely (only
>   remove a SWF after  it has been loaded, to avoid broken references)
>   and completely (nullify references to avoid memory leaks).

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

so basically remove the div with

```
$('#divId').remove();
```

and recreate a blank version of the div

Comment: This does not unload the flash application. For every flash application there is separate process running. I am looking for command that can stop this process.